# Processing JSON objects one by one in JSON stream during streaming in ASP.NET WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, streaming

I am trying to stream a large JSON file and deserialize item by item during the streaming.

I am using for this test https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/master/JsonTest/TestData/fathers.json.txt.

The problem is that i do not receive an error but my code does not seem to process the items one by one nor even process the JSON objects.

I am stuck and really do not know how to implement the portion which processes the stream object by object.

This is my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AMServices.Controllers
{
    public class FathersData
    {
        public Father[] fathers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Someone
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Father : Someone
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool married { get; set; }
        // Lists...
        public List<Son> sons { get; set; }
        // ... or arrays for collections, that's fine:
        public Daughter[] daughters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child : Someone
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Son : Child
    {
    }

    public class Daughter : Child
    {
        public string maidenName { get; set; }
    }

    public class StreamerController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly JsonSerializer _serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("streamer/stream")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> stream()
        {
            string apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/master/JsonTest/TestData/fathers.json.txt";

            using (var stream = await _client.GetStreamAsync(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                if (json == null)
                    StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                Father f = serializer.Deserialize<Father>(json);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f.name);    
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have modified the `using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))` to

```
while (json.Read())
{
    if (json.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        JObject objX = JObject.Load(json);
        Father f = objX.ToObject<Father>();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Name -> " + f.name);
    }
}
```

How do i change that i can stream and during this process item by item?

Comment: You can add a callback parameter to stream function like `Task stream(Action<Father> callback) {}` and then call it after deserialization. Async Enumerable is not available yet as it's an c# 8 feature. You can also take a look to the reactive extension (Rx)

Comment: @Kalten: Thanks for your comment. Could you please give a little example on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As async Enumerable is not availlable yet you can use a callback system. In the following sample I wrap deserialization logic in a class the will expose an event (`FatherReaded`).

```
async Task Main()
{
    await stream();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class FathersData
{
    public Father[] Fathers { get; set; }
}

public class Someone
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Father : Someone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Married { get; set; }
    // Lists...
    public List<Son> Sons { get; set; }
    // ... or arrays for collections, that's fine:
    public Daughter[] Daughters { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Someone
{
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class Son : Child
{
}

public class Daughter : Child
{
    public string maidenName { get; set; }
}

public async Task stream()
{

    var fatherReader = new FatherReader();
    fatherReader.FatherReaded += (s, f) => {
        //f.name.Dump();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f.Name);
    };

    string apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/master/JsonTest/TestData/fathers.json.txt";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        fatherReader.Read(stream);
    }
}

public class FatherReader
{
    public event System.EventHandler<Father> FatherReaded;

    public FatherReader()
    {

    }

    private void OnFatherReaded(Father father){
        FatherReaded?.Invoke(this, father);
    }

    public void Read(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            jsonReader.Read(); // Skip the first StartObject token

            while (jsonReader.Read())
            {
                if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    var father = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader, typeof(Father));
                    OnFatherReaded((Father)father);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Same but with observable (Rx) . The `Dump` method is an extension shorthand to `Console.WriteLine(this.ToString)`

```
public async Task stream()
{
    var fatherReader = new FatherReader();
    var observable = fatherReader.Observable;

    // Here you can chain many operator like Linq (filtre, transforme, ...)
    observable = observable
        .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("J"));

    observable.Subscribe(f => f.Name.Dump(), e => e.ToString().Dump());

    string apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/master/JsonTest/TestData/fathers.json.txt";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        fatherReader.Read(stream);
    }
}

public class FatherReader
{
    private Subject<Father> _observable = new Subject<Father>();
    public IObservable<Father> Observable => _observable.AsObservable();

    public FatherReader()
    {
    }

    private void OnFatherReaded(Father father)
    {
        _observable.OnNext(father);
    }

    public void Read(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                jsonReader.Read(); // Skip the first StartObject token

                while (jsonReader.Read())
                {
                    if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var father = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader, typeof(Father));
                            OnFatherReaded((Father)father);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _observable.OnError(ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _observable.OnError(ex);
        }

        _observable.OnCompleted();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `RootObject` and contain  `List<Father>` property be your Deserialize object, because of your URL JSON data `"father"` key contain an array rather than an object.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Father> fathers { get; set; }
}
```

Api use like this.

```
public class StreamerController : ApiController
{
    static readonly JsonSerializer _serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("streamer/stream")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> stream()
    {
        string apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/master/JsonTest/TestData/fathers.json.txt";

        using (var stream = await _client.GetStreamAsync(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            if (json == null)
                StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            RootObject f = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);  
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: But then i would not be able to deserialize item by item !?  I have modified my code a little bit with checking for the JSON StartObject but also with this it does not work.

Comment: @I'mSTORM way did you want to deserialize item by item? if you want your need to write your customer parse logic.

Comment: Cause i am receiving 3-5 million JSON items with a total volume of 5-7 Gigs and therefore i dont want to store them all first in memory before processing.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with your custom parse logic? Isnt it the similar to my posted examples?